# What is the best way to use linux utilities under windows?

Tags: windows, linux, cygwin

Linux utilities like sed, awk and other shell scripting features are awesome and life becomes a lot harder when I am developing on windows and cant use any of these.

People suggest to use cygwin for those who want the linux like tools under windows. But I feel cygwin will be an overkill for someone who only wants to use the handful commands.

Some say that Windows Services for Unix can also be a good alternative.

I have used none of these. Can some experienced programmer suggest best/simplest way to do this? of course apart from switching to linux itself.

Comment: There are native alternatives, have you head about PowerShell?

Comment: +1 PowerShell. If you're already used to Linux and just want to reapply old Linux skills, PowerShell is just short of utterly useless. But if you're trying to run *nix utilities in Windows because you have problems that you want to solve from a command shell, it's definitely worth your time to research PowerShell and the cmdlets ("commandlets"), scripts, add-ins, and PS-ready applications throughout the community that do well to solve the problems the old *nix tools were used for, where PS solves them in a much more manageable manner.

Comment: Not interested in learning powershell because I dont want to waste time learning any "windows skills".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) project is exactly what you're looking for. Unix command line tools ported to Windows.

Comment: This is working for me at the moment. I am also thankful to polemon's answer below which works well for exceptional situation.

Answer (score 12):

I've been using [UnxUtils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) which are ports of common GNU utilities to native Win32 for ages.

I should add that I've also used Cygwin (et al.)  and Microsoft's Services for Unix and neither of them were any good *for me* because they don't work as well as native versions from the command prompt, and using ksh/bash/whatever under Windows never really works right, even though I use ksh under unix all the time.

Comment: I use that too, very useful tool :)

Comment: Yep UnxUtils is awesome. Just unzip them to c:\bin\ and add c:\bin to the path. Done.

Answer (score 5):

I tried something like this quite often, but to be honest, none of it really works well.

I therefore suggest using a virtual machine (such as [VirtualBox](http://virtualbox.org)) and install a small linux inside that. You can easily move files from and to the guest system with shared folders.

Judging by my experience, it is the best solution I used so far.

Comment: I forgot to mention, that you can assign *any* folder as shared folder, including your whole C drive or your working directory.
With this, you can use your virtualized Linux as a shell and act upon those files in question.

Comment: What problems exactly did you encounter? I use GnuWin32 and have not had any real problems.

Comment: Oh this is really an interesting solution. I did try this out but dint know abotu the shared folder thing. I used a pen drive. :P So stupid of me.

Comment: *None* of it works really well? I'm not so sure. I use Cygwin daily. It's the best thing to happen to Windows, since 32-bit protected mode, IMHO. Works great.

Comment: Don't do this with VMWare 7 and 8. Both have a very buggy vmhfs file system emulation which causes a deadlock on the virtual machine. I had a few intense disk writing stuff and both versions crashed within 10min. This was state of mid 2013 and wasn't fixed when i checked again in 2014. Says a lot about how many people use shared folder in reality.

Answer (score 5):

I tried [Gow](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki) for some time, and it's nice. It offers 130 Unix-shell utilities for Windows. The contextual menu in the File explorer, to start a prompt in the current folder, is really handy.

Answer (score 4):

There's a [GNU port of many of the utils](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/). I find that quite useful.

If you need Perl, I recommend [Strawberry Perl.](http://strawberryperl.com/)

Answer (score 3):

The problem with most of the tools suggested here is that they don't get updated very often E.g. the last update GnuWin32 got was on *27 December 2010*; UnxUtils was last updated on *01 March 2007*.

I suggest [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/), a very good option which has a Win32 port of [Arch's *pacman*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_Linux#Pacman) package management system built-in. It's a spin-off from Cygwin like MSYS but much better than MSYS (lots of packages and gets updated almost daily) and (very light as opposed to) Cygwin.

It's a [rolling release distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_release) that works under Windows and thus you get the latest and greatest of [the packages](https://github.com/msys2/MSYS2-packages).  MSYS2 additionally has MinGW, provided in both x86 and x86_64 flavours.  They've their own list of packages - [MinGW packages](https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages).

Maintainers are very affable too.

Answer (score 1):

Install [msysGit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) (netinstaller), it comes with a (msys/minGW) shell environment.

It also adds a "open shell here" in explorer.

It's faster than Cygwin, but at the sacrifice of unix compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

MSYS is a common alternative for people who find CygWin excessive. It's still a special prompt, but it was originally intended to set up just enough Unix-compatibility to build programs using the MinGW compilers and the typical configure/make routine.

Using tools like sed and awk isn't going to work quite as expected in a normal Windows command prompt. It can be done to a point, but common usage involves command-line syntax that is normally interpreted by the shell, but which the Windows command prompt doesn't support. One example is wildcard file specifications. I've often found that Unix-centric tools aren't as usable on Windows as they assume the shell has expanded those wildcards into lists of files for them.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is stupid, but I usually search google for i.e.: "indent windows". You can select tools from mixed platforms. Lot of stuff from open systems has been ported on windows.