# Java keytool easy way to add server cert from url/port (for Windows)

Tags: windows, openssl, keytool

I want to import CA certificate into a Java keystore.
I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23162215/8253837) with some Unix commands.

I understand that `keytool` works in Windows the same way as in Linux, doesn't it?

But what about `openssl`?

I installed openssl in Windows, then ran it and it works normally. But how can I replace a code below?

```
</dev/null | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > ${HOST}.cert
```

Or can I replace `openssl` with something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to use [KeyStore Explorer](http://keystore-explorer.org). Just use the "Examine SSL" feature and then click on "Import":

[image]

Alternatively you can replace `</dev/null | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > ${HOST}.cert` with manual steps. If you execute

```
openssl s_client -connect -connect www.google.com:443
```

it will output something like this:

```
depth=2 OU = GlobalSign Root CA - R2, O = GlobalSign, CN = GlobalSign
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Google Trust Services, CN = Google Internet Authority G3
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = California, L = Mountain View, O = Google LLC, CN = www.google.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google LLC/CN=www.google.com
   i:/C=US/O=Google Trust Services/CN=Google Internet Authority G3
 1 s:/C=US/O=Google Trust Services/CN=Google Internet Authority G3
   i:/OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R2/O=GlobalSign/CN=GlobalSign
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEgjCCA2qgAwIBAgIIZ20sUt50wGgwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAwVDELMAkGA1UE
BhMCVVMxHjAcBgNVBAoTFUdvb2dsZSBUcnVzdCBTZXJ2aWNlczElMCMGA1UEAxMc
...
htkxJVFaLUXScpkNQagWzehkj9BGdV4oztKMgTU8hcZEsiDKF0aZmaMfAXAF6u0r
0n9sKu3Ap0uSR0+G4PVDcJkJzw2UiUsu8IkkHy3HjKt4zCCrATjZ4FPgtFHSWv8d
ZmUdWJhgJ30s/EvOKn1uQ6QlPWaCJKc9W6JaJQTX6PjPDMs0sK90ss9vCIJ0dDw5
ud+EC4cT
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google LLC/CN=www.google.com
issuer=/C=US/O=Google Trust Services/CN=Google Internet Authority G3
---
No client certificate CA names sent
```

Mark the lines starting with `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` up to `-----END CERTIFICATE-----` and copy them into a text editor. Save it as [host].crt. Then execute the keytool command.

If you want to automate these steps in a script, you'll have to install [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com) or one of the suggestions in [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519738/what-is-the-best-way-to-use-linux-utilities-under-windows).